# Javascript timer Usage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, timer

I have a case in my page,there i have six widgets(ie div) and each one calling one ajax function on different intervals(One div interval may be 20s,othere one it will be 30s).After getting result from server,i will update corresponding panels.Which is the best way to handle this scenario.Is it a good practice to keep  six different javascript timers for each of this panels(eg:like setInterval,setTimeout).If not,what is the best way to handle this scenario.

Comment: If they are updated simultaneously - just have a single timer that fires each 20 seconds

Comment: Are the ajax functions different for each div? Is there anyway you can club the requests?

Comment: And use JSON is order to send more that one information at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
duration = 20;

(function getMoreData(divIndex) {
    console.log("Process First");

    // Get ajax data for first div
    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
                dataFlag[divIndex]= true;

                // Process data...
                // Update "div 1"
            },
        error: function() {
                dataFlag[divIndex]= true;

                // Process error
            }
    });


    // Second div
    console.log("Process Second");


    // Get ajax data for second div
    $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
                dataFlag[divIndex]= true;

                // Process data...
                // Update "div 2"
            },
        error: function() {
                dataFlag[divIndex]= true;

                // Process error
            }
    });


    // Third div
    console.log("Process Third");


    // Get ajax data for second div
    $.ajax({
        url: url3,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
                dataFlag[divIndex]= true;

                // Process data...
                // Update "div 3"
            },
        error: function() {
                dataFlag[divIndex]= true;

                // Process error
            }
    });


    setTimeout(getMoreData, (duration * 1000));
})()
```

Comment: i didn get the usage of dataFlag.After getting result from server i need to update corresponding div.How can i do this.currently getMoreData not taking any parameters.Also there is a case that interval of each of these panels is different.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more explanation. You will have to update the div when the ajax success happens. Why do you need the interval to be different?

Comment: i want to design it like,all divs will call one common function by accepting one parameter.Also is it cpu intensive?if we are create settimeout for each six div,is it cpu intensive?each one will create an instance ...right?

Comment: different intervals bcoz,each panel having different functionality

Comment: @ATOzTOA..thanks for quick responses.I want to know whetehr is any way to manage it using Single Timer.Even i dont want to initalize all timers initially.

Comment: When do you want each div to update itself? Give me the time for each div. Like `div 1 : start after 10 seconds, repeat every 20 seconds`.

Comment: div 1 : start after 5 seconds, repeat every 20 seconds; div 2 : start after 7 seconds, repeat every 30 seconds;div 3 : start after 8 seconds, repeat every 20 seconds

Comment: Updated the answer... you have to modify the AJAX call to make it work. For testing, just set `dataFlag[divIndex]=true;`

Comment: still i have a doubt..in for loop ur creating multiple timer instances.Ur two dimensional array logic is fine.It should be for keeping interval for each divs.Is it posiible like i will intialize one timer on load.In call back function i will do a settimeout for other div.So each time i will update two dimensional array ,so that i know which div have to update next

Comment: No, it will become too complex to manage and will need its own complex logic to find the next interval. Just think, timeouts will be 5 sec, 2 sec, 1 sec, 12 sec(div1), 1 sec(div3), 9 sec(div2)... then what? Don't worry about CPU intensive, it won't add much.

Comment: @ATOzTOA..my requirement itself was how to manage it using single time rinstance.even i told six panels,it may be much more than that.

Comment: i dont much both about "start after".Purpose is all timers i want to start within 5 seconds.Interval is much important

Comment: Can you show part of your code for processing a div? What difference is there between the data in two divs?

Comment: If you need a single timer, then you will have to have all the div's to have same interval. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: yes..assume all div have same interval..then can u pls explain how to mange it

Comment: Is it OK to have all the divs being updated together? What exactly are you doing this for? Please explain your purpose.

Comment: each panel having set of bubbles.color of each bubble will change according to the result from server

Comment: @vmb Answer is updated. Can you share the code which uses the ajax call? Let's see if we can have a common code for ajax.

Comment: after getting resposnse from server,i will pass it to another function with div id and response as parameters

Comment: ya ajax call will be a common functionality

Comment: Update your question with your ajax call and the function you call after getting response.

Comment: getMoreDate have to accept parameters.Using above code is it update all the divs??

Comment: argument used in getMoreData will be used as data to ajax call.

Comment: yes..ur Solution will work...thanks for spending ur valuable time for fixing this issue..

Comment: I was doubtful,bcoz all request accessing same controller in server(MVC pattern)

Comment: Normally, all servers will have capability to support multiple requests.